# Hiding ComboBox if there are no items to display (MSAccess)

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've created an Access form and have implemented 3 "cascading combo boxes", so essentially, if the user selects an item in combobox 1, this will filter the items in combobox 2, which will then filter the items in combobox 3.

I am doing this using this code in VBA:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()

Me.Combobox2.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Table1].[SubColumn1]" & _
                               "FROM [Table1] " & _
                               "WHERE [Column1] = '" & Combobox1.Value & "' ;"                                
End Sub
```

This works great. However, there are instances where there will be no items to select in combobox2. My data in "Table1" looks like this:

```
| Column 1      | SubColumn1    | SubColumn2    |
|-------------  |-------------  |-------------  |
| Item 1        | Item 1A       |               |
| Item 1        | Item 1B       |               |
| Item 2        |               |               |
| Item 3        | Item 3A       | Item 3A1      |
| Item 3        | Item 3B       | Item 3B1      |
```

So as you can see, if the user selects Item 2 from combobox1, there will be no information in combobox2 or combobox3.

That being the case, I would like to potentially modify this code where if there are no items available in combobox2 or 3, these comboboxes will just be hidden.

I have tried wrapping this whole expression in if statement like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()
   if isnull(Me.Combobox2.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Table1].[SubColumn1]" & _
                                   "FROM [Table1] " & _
                                   "WHERE [Column1] = '" & Combobox1.Value & "' ;" ) 
     then me.combobox2.visible = false
     else: me.combobox2.visible = true                               
End Sub
```

This does not work and the not only do combobox2 and 3 not disappear, but there are now no items in the boxes whatsoever.

Can anyone assist?

Not sure how clear all this was, so let me know if i can answer any questions!

---

Update

Here are my two macros for the 3 comboboxes:

```
Private Sub ComboCause1_AfterUpdate()

Me.ComboCause2.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Cause of Injury].[Cause of Injury 2]" & _
                           "FROM [Cause of Injury] " & _
                           "WHERE [Cause of Injury] = '" & ComboCause1.Value & "' ;"
                           If Me.ComboCause2.ListCount < 2 Then
                           Me.ComboCause2.Visible = False
                           Me.ComboCause3.Visible = False
                           Me.Label2695.Visible = False
                           Me.Label2699.Visible = False
                           Else:
                           Me.ComboCause2.Visible = True
                           Me.Label2695.Visible = True
                           End If

End Sub
```

And

```
Private Sub ComboCause2_AfterUpdate()

Me.ComboCause3.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Cause of Injury].[Cause of Injury 3]" & _
                           "FROM [Cause of Injury] " & _
                           "WHERE [Cause of Injury 2] = '" & ComboCause2.Value & "' ;"
                           If Me.ComboCause3.ListCount < 2 Then
                           Me.ComboCause3.Visible = False
                           Me.Label2699.Visible = False
                           Else:
                           Me.ComboCause3.Visible = True
                           Me.Label2699.Visible = True
                           End If

End Sub
```

Comment: In the If statement for `ComboCause1_AfterUpdate` I think you need to remove the combo 3 test. I don't really understand the logic there. In the If statement for `ComboCause2_AfterUpdate` you need to change your `And` to an `Or`.

Comment: Got it to work! I've made some changes to my original edit if you want to take a look. Everything seems to be working though! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is check the ListCount... like:

```
If Me.Combobox2.Listcount = 0 then
   Me.Combobox2.Visible = False
Else
   Me.Combobox2.Visible = True
EndIf
```

Comment: I really like this code, but I am running into an issue: The combobox3 doesn't seem to want to disappear. So if there is no combobox2, there should be no combobox3. And if there is a combobox2, but there are no items in combobox3, combobox3 should disappear. I've made an update to my code. Can you check it out?

Comment: It looks like you figured this out on your own...  I was giving you a sample of how you could hide / show any combo box based upon another. To cascade to more combo's, simply add the code like you did in your updated post.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You could first create a recordset with your SQL string and then test whether the recordset is empty before assigning your row source:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT [Table1].[SubColumn1]" & _
                           "FROM [Table1] " & _
                           "WHERE [Column1] = '" & Combobox1.Value & "' ;"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

If rs.EOF Then
    Me.Combobox2.Visible = False
Else
    Me.Combobox2.Visible = True
    Me.Combobox2.RowSource = strSQL
End If

Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

`IsNull()` will not be able to evaluate the results of a query, or the number of items listed in the combobox. Recordsets can be evaluated using `.EOF` to determine whether the results are empty. This may not be the most efficient way to do it but it should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Set combos 2 and 3 as Not Visible in design.

Include fields 2 and 3 as hidden columns in combo 1. Then in combo 1 AfterUpdate:

```
Me.combo2.Visible = Me.combo1.Column(1) <> ""
Me.combo3.Visible = Me.combo1.Column(2) <> ""
```

Then do similar in combo 2 to set visibility of combo 3.

If you are navigating records, probably also need code in the OnCurrent event to set visibility of combos 2 and 3.

Be aware this will not work nice in Continuous or Datasheet view. However, combobox Enabled property can be set with Conditional Formatting and this will work in Continuous and Datasheet view.

Recommend you give comboboxes more meaningful names.